# http get request to whois using postman

Tags: rest, http, postman

I am trying to send a http get request to [whois](https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-api-doc.php) application to get some information.

I do this using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), the target url is `http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=google.com&username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx`

and i have tried to **add parameters in header**, but when i add them i face with an error `The parameter domainName is missing`.
here is the picture of postman:
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your graphic, you added the values as **headers**. You need to click on "Params", next to the URL, and add the values there!